# Access SFTP directory with some users

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, sftp

I try to access sftp directory in Linux but i got this error

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

and in journal i got

```
sshd[24404]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
```

my directory is /var/sftp/files :

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mai 24 13:48 sftp
```

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserFTP root 4096 Mai 24 13:48 files
```

And I have added these lines to /etc/ssh/sshd_config :

```
Match User UserFTP
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/%u
        PermitTunnel no
        AllowAgentForwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
```

then I restart the ssh service.

Note: I use the same user to access ftp also.

Can any one help me and give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://serverfault.com/questions/418931/sftp-fatal-bad-ownership-or-modes-for-chroot-directory-ubuntu-12-04/418937?newreg=899788119d964533ab88df21a3c0fbd2

`%u` presents username. The chroot directory and all of its parents must not have group or world write capabilities (ie `chmod 755`). The chroot directory and all of its parents must be owned by root. Subdirectory may own UserFTP.

For user `UserFTP`:

```bash
% mkdir -p /var/sftp/UserFTP/files
% chown root:root /var/sftp/UserFTP
% chmod 755 /var/sftp/UserFTP

% chown UserFTP /var/sftp/UserFTP/files
```

```bash
% ls -ld /var/sftp/UserFTP
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 24. kvě 15.29 /var/sftp/UserFTP/

% ls -ld /var/sftp/UserFTP/files 
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserFTP root 4096 26. kvě 12.07 /var/sftp/UserFTP/files/
```

```
$ sftp UserFTP@localhost
sftp> cd files
sftp> put file123
```

```
% ls /var/sftp/UserFTP/files
file123
```

Comment: I did as you describe but it still doesn`t work
To connect to sftp I use "sftp UserFTP@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" @MarrekNožka

Comment: This configuration works for me. I rewrited `lftp` to `sftp`. What mean "doesn`t work To connect"? Same error in journal? Did yout restart SSHd? Note: Unix/Linux systems is CaseSensitive.